# re-answering a question bug

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

I just changed my mind about an answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985364/jquery-window-resize-help-please), so I accepted a different answer. I received 2 reputation points for this:

```
 +2  21 mins ago    accepted    jquery window resize help please
```

Not that I am ungrateful, but this seems exploitable, as you can arbitrarily increase your reputation by changing accepted answers.

Comment: Wait, so is this a bug or a feature (removal) request?

Comment: I'm assuming i'ts a bug, because it thinks, I just answered my question as oppose to just simply switching the answers to a better more elaborated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an issue, because at the same time you *received* the 2 rep for accepting that answer, you also *lost* the 2 rep you had received when accepting the previous answer (or, if you will, you changed history in the way that you never received those two points in the first place). In other words, there's no net gain.

Comment: That, I didn't notice, but I just thought maybe I was helping, so cool :) should I mark this as the right answer, and are you absolutely sure?